# What is the "wildcard character"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

What character would act as a wild card in Objective-C? I have tried using *, but no luck. I am trying to get a value that is passed through a URL like this:

```
NSString *clearQuery = [query stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"q=set&mode=*&session=" withString:@""];
```

I need it to return only the session value. The mode could be a lot of things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it assumable that `q`, `mode` and `session` will always appear in the query string in that order? Normally in URL query strings the order of parameters could be anything.

Comment: Yes because I control the page where it is passed from and there is no way that it could be switched around.

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or `rangeOfString:...` with `NSRegularExpressionSearch` instead.  `-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:]` matches literal strings, not patterns of any sort.

Comment: Could you please provide some code to help me get started? I looked it up, but I can't seem to find an example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you want to use NSString rangeOfString... with NSRegularExpressionSearch, you can get the range of the string that matches the pattern and remove that range from a NSMutableString.  If you want to use NSRegularExpression, create a regular expression with the pattern you want to match and use NSRegularExpression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such wildcard.

You might look into the new `NSRegularExpression` class, but this needs 4.0 at minimum.